# popup pointing to a div and positioned correctly inside screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on an HTML website. I have some divs, on mouse over, I need to have some sort of a popup dialog. The dialog should have an arrow pointing to the div that I have the mouse on.

My problem is that I dont know how to make the popup point to the wanted div, also the popup should Appear above the mouse, unless there is no space on the screen it appears under the mouse.

I tried to calculate some positions and decide where the popup should be to stahy in the screen but it was hard and confusing.
Sorry if this seems like a "give me code" question but it isn't, I am just looking for hints to show the div correctly and have it pointed to the div. Any Third party library or tips are appreciated.

BTW I am working on HTML5 + javascript + jquery

Comment: Although you did describe your problem, it is greatly appreciated to be able to see some code. Consider adding some code so that your question will have a much higher value

Answer (score 0):

For the general popup positioning (tooltip will need `position: absolute`:

```
$('.elements').hover(function(e) {
    var tooltipX = e.pageX + 40;
    var tooltipY = e.pageY + 40;

    $('#tooltip').css({
        'left': tooltipX,
        'top': tooltipY
    });
    $('#tooltip').fadeIn('fast');
}, function(e) {
    $('#tooltip').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

For the arrow, you could use SVG or better yet, Raphael.js at http://raphaeljs.com/